# Heuristics as to when $\frac{x-c_1}{c_2-c_1}$ and similar forms are linear and form a line?

Tags: linear-transformations

Heuristics as to when $f(x)=\frac{x-c_1}{c_2-c_1}$ and similar forms are linear and form a line?

By *similar forms* I mean that I started to speculate as to how much one can "add stuff" to the above simple case and still know that the function is a linear function and its graph is a line.

Intuitively one can add, subtract and do multiplications by constants. One could also add linear functions to it and still retain linearity. But linearity would surely be broken if one adds a nonlinear function $\eta(x)$ like $h(x)=f(x)+\eta(x)$?

So additivity and homogeneity do not suffice, but they have some constraints as to what can be added and what can be used as multiplier. What are these constraints?

Comment: What do you call "similar forms" and what is $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust More clear?

Comment: As clear as *stuff* can be.

Comment: Use the term 'linear functional' very carefully. $f(x)=\frac{x-c_1}{c_2-c_1}$ is a linear _functional_ only for $c_1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affine functions of one variable are of the form

$$ax+b$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Nothing more to say.

Comment: This is all there is to functions that are linear and form a line? So then one only needs to be able to factor the function into that form. Well makes sense, since that's the line equation.

Comment: @mavavilj: that's it. Strictly speaking, a linear function is of the form $ax$. With an added constant, it is said affine.

Answer (score 0):

**Generalization**

Consider  the function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ as follows $$f(x)={a^Tx+b\over c^Tx+d}$$where $a,c\in \Bbb R^n$ and $b,d\in\Bbb R$. The case where $a=0$ , $b=0$ is trivial, so we investigate the rest. If $f(x)$ is affine, then $e\in \Bbb R^n$ , $f\in \Bbb R$ exist such that $$f(x)=e^Tx+f$$by substitution we obtain $${a^Tx+b\over c^Tx+d}=e^Tx+f\\a^Tx+b=x^Tce^Tx+df+(fc+de)^Tx$$which yields to $$b=df\\ce^T=0\\fc+de=a$$some cases are worth studying:

---

**Case 1** $d=0$

In this case $b=0$ and we obtain $a=fc$ with $f\ne 0$ and we have $$f(x)={a^Tx\over c^Tx}=f{c^Tx\over c^Tx}$$ which is not affine over $\Bbb R^n$ since the function is not defined for $c^Tx=0$. Therefore **the case $d=0$ doesn't lead to affinity**.

---

**Case 2** $d\ne 0$ , $c=0$

We obtain$$f={b\over d}\\de=a$$which means that **affinity happens in this case without extra assumptions.**

---

**Case 3** $d\ne0$ and $c\ne 0$

The equations lead to $$f={b\over d}\\ec^T=0\\fc+de=a$$from $$ec^T=0$$ we obtain $ec^Tc=e\cdot ||c||^2=0$ and since $c\ne 0$ we have $e=0$ therefore $$f={b\over d}\\fc=a$$ and since $c^Tx+d=0$ has infinitely many roots, then **this case either doesn't lead to affinity**.

> **Conclusion**
>
> The only case leading to affinity is $c=0$ and $d\ne 0$.

Comment: The equivalence is not perfect, as the denominator can vanish.

Comment: In which case you mean? It's not needed to study such cases since the equivalence must hold on infinitely many points. More precisely, the points for which the equivalence is eliminated, form a zero-measure subset of $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: What you consider "cases not needed" in fact completely destroys the affinity property. At *every* point.

Comment: Yes you are right. I mean the cases that the function is well defined (not $\pm\infty$ valued) e.g for the case $d\ne 0$ and $c=0$ the domain is $\Bbb R^n$ but I will edit my answer.

Comment: For the function to be defined everywhere, you need to explicitly state its value at the singular points (taking the limit for proper continuation), and this is absolutely equivalent to simplifying the form to $ax+b$. An homographic form is inappropriate.